# How to run conroller methods within a event in Ext JS 4.2 (Sencha Architect)

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

I have in Architect the following structure.

A controller that includes a view (example MyPanelView)

In the MyPanelView, you can have a button, and give it an itemId. Then you can 
bind it to a click event. You can use the click event (inline) without the controller,
or you can move the event to the controller. That works fine.

But what about these events? afterrender, beforerender, etc..? If you move this up to 
the controller, the event does not get fired there.

Since this is not working, how could I acces the controller methods within
the afterrender function of the panel?

```
onAfterrenderMyPanelView : function(component, eOpts) {
   this.getRefToOtherPanel() //not working
}
```

Thanks in advance! I'm lost..

Chris.

Comment: There's no "special" events, the controller will pick up anything. The 2 most common causes are either that the event has fired before you've called `control()`, or your selector for the event is not matching.

Comment: thanks, this was the case.. the event was fired before the control()

Answer (score 1):

You can set up listeners and event handlers in your controller like this (example from the Sencha docs):

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Users', {
     extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

     init: function() {
         this.control({
             'viewport > panel': { //<-- ComponentQuery
                 render: this.onPanelRendered //<-- event handler
             }
         });
     },

     onPanelRendered: function() {
         console.log('The panel was rendered');
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, this was exactly what I had done. The event that I used happend before the this.control() ..so it could not be captured.